# Revoke application authorization on facebook logout android sdk3.5

Tags: android, facebook

***[ SOLVED MYSELF. SEE THE ANSWER FOR SOLUTION. ]***

I used android facebook sdk 3.5 in my application for login. Now when user logout from facebook in my application, i simply follwing below codes to logout.

```
session=new Session(context);
                Session.setActiveSession(session);
                session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
```

Now, if user again try to login to facebook, I want to show login box as another user instead of doing login automatically from sessioncache. 
**[ remember that when your device has facebook application installed. Above problem only exist when device has facebook application else it is working fine. ]**

I have googled this problem but not found the solution for SDK 3.5 . So how to force to show login box when user try to login again??

The only idea i got is we need to deauthorize our application on logout. So it will be asked to enter login again. Is this corret? if yes, then how can we deauthorize our app using sdk 3.5 ?

Comment: people please provide link if has solution instead of down rating. Link will be fine for me instead of direct solution in your word.

Answer (score -1):

Finally i succeed in revoking authorization. here is the code.

```
Request deAuthorizeRequest=new Request(session, "/me/permissions", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            ((BaseFunctions) getActivity()).Log("unlink account : "+response.toString());
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
});         
deAuthorizeRequest.executeAsync();
```

But it seems that this solved my problem partial. It is not showing login box dialog. Need to find solution for it. :)

Comment: it seems without checking, someone down rating my answers. you are getting nothing by doing this with wrong intention.